# OpenGL 3 equivalent of GLUTesselator?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I was wondering, since things like display lists are now deprecated, I'm thinking the GLU polygon tesselator is probably also deprecated. What is the new and correct way of creating concave or complex polygons and complying with the new GL 3 standard? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GLUT is not and was never a part of OpenGL.

If you need this functionality then use another library that provides it and can use VBOs or write it yourself.

Starting with OpenGL 4 there is also hardware tesselation support.

Comment: Afaik, OpenGL 4 tesselation replaces triangles with multiple smaller triangles, but does not triangulate concave polygons. Or does it?

Comment: Quads are supported as an input for the tesselator, but not n-gons.

If the GLUT "tesselation" just splits a n-gons in triangles then you are correct, that the hardware tesselation is something different.